# How to write incremental lines in Vim?

Tags: vimscript

There comes a time where I'm in a situation of downloading multiple files. And the name of files are in series. Something like.

```
http://www.example.com/files/images/img01.jpg
http://www.example.com/files/images/img02.jpg
http://www.example.com/files/images/img03.jpg
...
```

and so on.

Suppose there are files from `img01.jpg` to `img49.jpg`. What is the best way to write the full URL of the image on each line *(as done above)* without repetition? So that I can pass `wget` the list with `-i` parameter?

**P.S.**: Don't tell me I can do `curl http://www.example.com/files/images/img{01,49}.jpg` in bash to accomplish my work.

Comment: You can do `curl http://www.example.com/files/images/img{01,49}.jpg` in bash to accomplish your work.

Comment: @romainl You **forced** me to sign up to reply to your comment. Now let me tell you that I'm using Windows. and `{` & `}` are bash expansion. So no luck on *Powershell*, at least.

Comment: Well, you will need to log in to accept my answer anyway so…

Comment: I got a problem with my accounts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269958/181377

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a different version, that assumes you have Vim [7.4.754](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3a304b23823b089e499063e8211c5695d049f3ba) (25 Jun 2015) or newer:

If you have this line:

```
http://www.example.com/files/images/img01.jpg
```

Now copy and paste it 48 times `yy48p`. Then go to the *second line*, visually block select the 01 down to the bottom and press `g<C-A>`

You might need to adjust your `'nrformat'` settings as romainl said in his answer.

Comment: FYI, I'd like to also point the vim help page, `:help v_g_CTRL-A` which I got pointed by through my own question https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/visual-block-mode-edit-with-sequential-number

Answer (score 13):

1. Assuming you have this line:

   ```
   http://www.example.com/files/images/img01.jpg
   ```
2. Start recording in some alphabetic register, say `q`:

   ```
   qq
   ```
3. Yank the line:

   ```
   yy
   ```
4. Put it below the current line:

   ```
   p
   ```
5. Increment the number:

   ```
   <C-a>
   ```
6. Stop the recording:

   ```
   q
   ```
7. Play it back 47 times:

   ```
   47@q
   ```

In short:

```
qqyyp<C-a>q47@q
```

Note that you will almost certainly need to tell Vim to stop considering numbers starting with `0` as octal numbers:

```
:set nrformats-=octal
```

Comment: Your answer was cool too, but I chose Christian's because it involves fewer keystrokes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `:substitute` command together with `sub-replace-\=`, and using the line numbers to get the increments.

You can start with the line

```
http://www.example.com/files/images/img01.jpg
```

and duplicate it enough times with the `yy48p`. After that, the substitute command would be

```
:%s/01/\=printf('%02d', line('.'))
```

A more general form to perform the same action is

```
%s/img\zs\d\{2}/\=printf('%02d', line('.'))
```

Where you use `\zs`to anchor the number reference to certain location in the pattern (if there were multiple numbers) and don't need to necessarily have the same number on each line when you start the substitution. You can also include an offset if needed:

```
%s/img\zs\d\{2}/\=printf('%02d', line('.')+4)
```

Comment: It's too much for this trivial problem. :P By the way thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like Cajanus, start with one line:

```
http://www.example.com/files/images/img01.jpg
```

and duplicate it 48 times:

```
yy48p
```

Using visincr.vim, use ctrl-v to visual-block select the 01s.  Then

```
:II 1 0
```

You can get visincr.vim from

```
http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VISINCR
```