# Visual Block Mode edit with sequential number

Tags: visual-mode, macro, visual-block, line-numbers

Suppose I'd like to create a list

```
- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
```

what Is the smartest way to create such?

My attempt would be to <kbd>i</kbd>`- "1"`<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>yy</kbd><kbd>pp</kbd> to get

```
- "1"
- "1"
- "1"
```

and then jump to the second line's 1 <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

BUT: doing this for a list of e.g. 100 (also thinking about the second digit) is not what I want to do with technique above...

I am using nvim v0.3.5 von archLinux, but i don't think, that that does matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on your usecase the following might be useful:

Create the entries all with the number "1":

```
- "1"
- "1"
- "1"
- "1"
```

Then go to the second "1" and press <kbd>V</kbd> to start line-wise visual. Then move down to the last "1". So now all but the first "1" is selected.

Now hit <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> and you get

```
- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
- "4"
```

See `:help v_g_CTRL-A`

**Update:** What if a I need a new number "3" and all following should be increased by one?

First insert the new line:

```
- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
- "3"
- "4"
```

Then go to the second "3", hit <kbd>V</kbd> and move down to the end of the list. Now hit <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> (without leading `g`) and the selected numbers are increased by one.

You get:

```
- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
- "4"
- "5"
```

Comment: and additional +1 for the `:help v_g_CTRL-A`

Comment: I had no clue of `v_g_CTRL-A`, brilliant! you have my vote.

Comment: Note that `v_g_CTRL-A` is only available since vim 8.1.

Comment: When I'm doing this using vim 9, it replaces all the 1's by 2's rather than giving the sequential numbering... not sure what's the reason.

Comment: @Nigu Just tested with vim 9.0.861 and 9.0.1128. It works as described. Did you forget the `g` before `Ctrl-a` ?

Comment: Seems like I must have forgotten the `g` somehow before. Good guess, it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter macro version.

First write a single line with the contents

```
- "1"
```

Then type the following:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>—start recording
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>—Duplicate the line
- <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>—Increment the number
- <kbd>q</kbd>—End the recording
- <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>—Replay 98 times

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follow:

- Somewhere in your file (before where you want your list), add a line with the first number - 1 (most likely 0),
- Make a mark at this place (`ma`)
- Make an empty line where you want your list and make another mark there (`mb`)

Your file would, at this point, look like this (The lines 1 and 2 don't matter, they are just here to say where the marks are):

[image]

- Record the following macro:

```
    qq                          // Start the macro in register q
    `a                          // go to mark a
    CTRL-a                      // Increase the number
    yiw                         // Copy the number
    `b                          // Go to mark b
    i- "                        // Go in insert mode, insert - "
    <esc>p                      // leave the insert mode and paste the number
    A"<CR><esc>                 // Closes the quote, add a new line and leave the insert mode
    mb                          // Update the mark b to be here
    q                           // Stop recording the macro

    100@q                       // Run the macro 100 times
```

You can delete the line where the mark a is, as it was just to store the counter.

And *voila*.

Comment: I like the idea of using a variable. Is there an option to save (and increase) this variable inside a register? That would make the macro much shorter.

Comment: I am not sure it is easily possible (without using a `:` command, which is fine too, but I don't think that would make the macro simpler). Maybe someone will have a suggestion to improve it?